# Restoring CustomView Settings in Excel Sheet via MATLAB ActiveX Server

Tags: excel, matlab, activex

I am using an ActiveX server to modify the formatting in an Excel spreadsheet through MATLAB. I need to generate a new spreadsheet and I want the same CustomView settings in this sheet as those previously set in an older spreadsheet. Here I load the older spreadsheet and I am able to view the number of CustomViews that I've defined through Excel.

```
e = actxserver ('Excel.Application'); % open Activex server
ewb = e.Workbooks.Open(fileName); % open file (enter full path!)

>> ewb.CustomViews.get
      Application: [1x1 Interface.000208D5_0000_0000_C000_000000000046]
      Creator: 'xlCreatorCode'
      Parent: [1x1 Interface.000208DA_0000_0000_C000_000000000046]
      Count: 3
```

This is the part that I am stuck on as I don't know how to "transfer" these settings to another sheet. I've found some [ActiveX documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb255966%28v=office.12%29.aspx) but it makes no mention of how I might be able to store these settings and use them in another spreadsheet.

What I have in mind is something like...

```
myCustomViews = ewb.CustomViews;
save('myCustomViews.mat','myCustomViews');

% 
%
% Clear all and close/quit instance of actxserver
%
%

e = actxserver('Excel.Application');
newEwb = e.Workbooks.Open(newFileName);

load myCustomViews.mat;

newEwb.CustomViews = myCustomViews;
```

But I know this won't work because (1) `myCustomViews` doesn't seem to contain any information about the view, like which columns/rows were hidden, zoom level, etc... and (2) it's not possible to load the `myCustomViews` object properly after saving it. (MATLAB says it cannot load the interface)